# Use Jest and spread operator without babel?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

Is it possible to use the spread operator in code with Jest and without babel if the node engine is 8+?

I am dropping support for Node.js <8 in my app and assumed I could remove all babel dependencies and transpiling from `package.json`, however `npm run jest` fails immediately with these types of errors:

```
 FAIL  test/workers/repository/onboarding.spec.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

/Users/me/project/lib/workers/repository/onboarding.js: Unexpected token (13:17)
    11 |
    12 | async function createOnboardingBranch(inputConfig) {
  > 13 |   let config = { ...inputConfig };
       |                  ^
```

Is there any way to get Jest to work without needing to add back all the babel dependencies and configuration?

Node.js version: 8.9.0
Jest version: 20.0.4
jest config in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "cacheDirectory": ".cache/jest",
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "lib/**/*.js"
  ],
  "coverageReporters": [
    "json",
    "lcov",
    "text-summary"
  ],
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/chai.js"
},
```

Edit:

I have been able to narrow my babel configuration down to just one plugin: `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` and configure babel in `package.json` like so:

```
"babel": {
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
},
```

Taking this out or attempting to use babel-preset env causes Jest to fail on the spread operator again.

Comment: You can, if you only use features supported by Node 8. Spread properties are not an official feature of the language yet.

Comment: I had wondered that, but found the spread operator listed as supported on http://node.green/. The code itself appears to run fine on Node.js 8 without any transpilation - it's only tests failing.

Comment: That looks like a babel error still, are you sure you removed `babel-jest`? I think it is auto loaded so you may need to disable it if the dependency is from somewhere else.

Comment: babel-jest is automatically loaded by Jest I think. I did try adding `transforms: {}` but also failed.

Comment: I reconfirmed that setting `"transform": {},` in my jest config results in same erroring. i.e. test suites fail to run due to spread operator.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are using [rest/spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which is still only a proposal. However, you should be able to use it as of [Node.js 8.6 (and 8.2.1 with a flag)](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--object-rest-spread-properties).

Comment: I'm guessing it might be Jest's own parsing of JS for mocking that is causing it? Will raise it as an issue in GitHub if there's no answer here.